# Record Button on Instruments Xcode

Tags: ios5, xcode5, xcode-instruments

actually I am new to Xcode Instruments, there are two Recording buttons on Instruments IDE one the top and second one in the bottom. Can some one explain or refer why the Record button in the top doesnt perform any actions

Comment: What record button in the bottom?

Comment: In The IDE we have Play record and pause buttons http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/04/08/ios-automated-tests-with-uiautomation#4.4 ... Interactively record interaction section and 4 th point